# Cairo-dock removal problem

Tags: cairo-dock

I installed Cairo-dock using The Software Center, I didn't like it so I uninstalled it. It is still there, it still opens, but it isn't marked as installed anymore.

Comment: You can try running `sudo apt-get remove cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins` in a terminal.

Comment: Package 'cairo-dock-plug-ins' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'cairo-dock' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.

Comment: I guess you also want to check `sudo apt-get remove cairo-dock-core`

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, to remove the main Cairo-dock packages from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove cairo-dock cairo-dock-core
```

If you want to make sure other packages are removed, you can also add the following:

```
cairo-dock-plug-ins cairo-dock-plug-ins-data cairo-dock-data
```