# Difference between command-line commands regarding uninstalling Cairo-Dock?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, uninstall, cairo-dock

#### The Basis

In order to uninstall Cairo-Dock completely, [@Nattgew's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/527169/425299) to this question says that the following should be input (inputted?) into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove cairo-dock cairo-dock-core cairo-dock-plug-ins cairo-dock-plug-ins-data cairo-dock-data
```

But @Sylvain_Pineau [says](https://askubuntu.com/a/531413/425299) to input into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock cairo-dock-core cairo-dock-data libgldi-dev libgldi3
```

And yet @Muzaffar, on the other hand, [says](https://askubuntu.com/a/596931/425299) to input into the terminal a far simpler command string:

```
sudo apt-get-purge cairo-dock-core
```

---

#### The Questions

So my questions are as follows:

1. What is the difference between `purge` and `remove`?
2. Why do some of the above include commands that others don't necessarily include?
3. Which should I use? I just want to uninstall Cairo-Dock, config files and all. As if, you know, *I had uninstalled it*. Lol. I've already "uninstalled" it via the Ubuntu Software Center, and it shows it as not being installed in there as well.
4. ***Which, for the love of all that is computerised, is it: "input" or "inputted"?*** (Lmao.)

---

**EDIT**: Listen, I'm very confused now. I don't know which of these answers is the best answer, and I honestly have no clue what I'm doing here as I'm very much a beginner with Linux in general, let alone command line. Please, I don't want to screw up my system. I just want to uninstall the programme completely, like using [Revo Uninstaller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revo_Uninstaller) on Windows. That's *all I want to do*.

It's probably my own inexperience here, but it seems like this is way more complicated than it needs to be...

---

#### The Specs

- **Make & Model**: Dell Inspiron N5010
- **Operating System**: Ubuntu 15.04
- **GUI Environment**: Unity
- **Terminal Used**: Terminal (Gnome-terminal), v3.14.2-0ubuntu3

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between purge and remove?

`remove` will remove the package(s) leaving the package(s)'s configuration files; `purge` will remove the package(s) without leaving the package(s)'s configuration files<del>; *however their actual behavior is package-dependent*: I've seen purged applications that after a reinstallation still held their old configuration</del>.

> Why do some of the above include commands that others don't necessarily include?

Because they attempt, more or less successfully (this is the difference between them) to remove the package's dependencies along with the package.

To be honest, I don't consider removing each dependency manually a good way to do that; *to remove and purge a package and all of its dependencies there is a way in `apt-get` which will take care of the specific case properly and that will remove and purge not more and not less than what is not necessary anymore* (and that is general enough that it will work for any package just by replacing the package's name):

```
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock && \
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge cairo-dock
```

- `sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock`: Removes and purges `cairo-dock`;
- `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge cairo-dock`: Removes and purges each `cairo-dock` dependecy *but* those needed by other packages;

Alternatively, to keep the `cairo-dock`'s and `cairo-dock`'s dependencies configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get remove cairo-dock && \
sudo apt-get autoremove cairo-dock
```

> Which should I do? I just want to uninstall Cairo-Dock, config files and all. As if, you know, I had uninstalled it. Lol. I've already "uninstalled" it via the Ubuntu Software Center, and it shows it as not being installed in there as well.

The first method proposed above:

```
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock && \
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge cairo-dock`
```

It will purge `cairo-dock`'s configuration files and remove and purge not more and not less than what is not necessary anymore.

> Which, for the love of all that is computerised, is it: "input" or "inputted"?

"Inputted" sounds pretty awkward. I'd second "input": https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30684/inputted-or-input.

Comment: [nods] I agree completely. *Inputted* sounds weird(er) and makes sense according to [@MT_Head's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/30687/127902) regarding parts of speech.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer to some of your question: `purge` is different respect `remove` because it deletes also the configuration  files in addition to all the packages.
If you want to completely remove Cairo Dock with all the configuration file you should use `purge` for the motivation I said before.

Comment: So just as @kos said, right? :)

Comment: @SarahofGaia To be fair, this was posted minutes before mine. However I saw this when I was mid-answering already, and I thought mine was more comprehensive, so I posted it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with purge-vs-remove. Some packages include configuration files in `/etc/` as part of their package. It is expected that some of these might have been edited by the user so `apt remove` doesn't remove them if you uninstall a package. `apt purge` will. Neither has any effect on user configuration files in your home directory.

Now, as for removing all these things, everything cairo-dock `depends` on `cairo-dock-core` directly or otherwise. If you `remove` or `purge` that, everything else gets removed. So that's quite smart.

However, `purge` will only purge configuration files for explicitly stated packages. If you purge something that takes out other packages, they will only be *removed*. [`cairo-dock-core` doesn't have any configuration files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/cairo-dock-core/filelist). There's no point purging it.

All three seem fairly equivilent for your purposes. Targeting just `cairo-dock-core` is clever, but it doesn't *do* anything fancier.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this contradict with @kos's answer above?

Comment: @SarahofGaia No, it doesn't counterdict my answer, it tackles the question from another point of view. To make a comparison, my answer suggests to dismantle a pile of boxes starting from the top box; Oli's answer puts the spotlight on the fact that the methods you outlined in your question are clever because they just smash the bottom box. Oli's answer is very specific to this case. However in general beware of targeting random core packages to remove the packages which depend on it, unless you *really* know what you're doing; it's very easy to blow up unwanted things.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what I'm doing. I just want to uninstall the programme completely; that's all... T_T Like with using [Revo Uninstaller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revo_Uninstaller) on Windows 7.